# Change Language on Spinner

Tags: android, locale, android-spinner

I am trying this all from last week . I tried to change the language on spinner activity.
Though i am able to change the language but once I the change of language MainActivity continue to refresh. My point is something wrong with refresh() function.Any pointers or what i am doing wrong.Here is my functions :-

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
 if(position == 0){
            setLocale("fr");              
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Locale in French !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }
          if(position == 1){
              setLocale("es");
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Locale in Spain !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }
          if(position == 2){
              setLocale("en");
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Locale in English !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }
          return true;

}

public void setLocale(String localeCode){
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        refresh();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    }

  private void refresh() {
      finish();
       //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

     // Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, OpertingSystemFragment.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the solution for the above problem

```
private void setAdapterToSpinner() {
    languageList.clear();
    languageList.add("Select language");
    languageList.add("English");
    languageList.add("हिंदी");
    languageAdapter=new LanguageAdapter(context,languageList);
    spinnerLanguage.setAdapter(languageAdapter);
    spinnerLanguage.setSelection(SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferenceInt(context,"selection",0));
    spinnerLanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String currentLanguage= SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferenceString(context,"Language","en");
          if(i==2){
              if(currentLanguage!="hi") {
                  setLocaleLanguage("hi");
                  SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceString(context, "Language", "hi");
                  SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceInt(context,"selection",2);
                  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.loginFragmentContainer, new LoginFragment(), "");
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();
              }
          }else if(i==1){
              if(currentLanguage!="en") {
                  setLocaleLanguage("en");
                  SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceInt(context,"selection",1);
                  SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceString(context, "Language", "en");
                  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.loginFragmentContainer, new LoginFragment(), "");
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();
              }

          }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

public void setLocaleLanguage(String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you explain in a few words what was the problem and what is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whats are you trying to acheive and what is that you get to see? From the code, I understand that finish the current activity and then you start the MainActivity. This code should finish the activity and launch again.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When i used above code Screen refreshes after getting intent .Means after every 5 sec screen refreshes .

Comment: So above code is not also working at all .I know something little i am missing in refresh .